# Texture appears fine in texture/solid view but appears black in material view

Tags: texturing, materials

I have a texture that I dragged and dropped onto the model, and it appears properly(texture corresponds to the area)

[image: texture is fine in solid view]

but black in material mode,
so when I export the model to pmx/obj no texture shows up.

[image: texture appears black in material view]

Comment: No light/lamp in the scene?

Comment: Do you have a UV mapping in place? Is the texture appearing in the material texture slots? Do you have a lamp hidden? Can you set the material to Shadeless to check without a lamp?

Comment: @lemon i tried adding a light, still black

Comment: @Craig D Jones i dont have a uv map, is there a way to auto assign a UV map? because like I said i just dragged and dropped the texture and it assigned fine

Comment: I would assume you want to at least look at the Map tab there to see if there is a default UVMap to toggle on to make sure it uses that mapping on export...